# Superscript/subscript in R

Tags: r, plotmath

I would like to have on a plot the following:

[image]

I am using this code, but I don't get the expected outcome.

```
text(4.4,0.5, expression(paste(P[B6.Rag^"-/-"_NOD.Rag^"-/-"], "=2.9x10^-4")), cex = 1.3)
```

Thanks

Comment: `paste` is not valid, are you quotes right? and what is the desired appearance?

Comment: I added above the expected output

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Spacedman Error: unexpected input in "   text(4.4,0.5, expression(paste(P[B6.Rag^"-/-"_"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How does this look?

```
plot(1:10, type="n");
text(5,5, expression(P[`B6.Rag-/-_NOD.Rag-/-`] == 2.8 %*% 10^-4), cex = 1.3)
```

[image]

Comment: The help for `plotmath` is useful here - and should show you all the possibilities, except I don't see the use of back-quotes to put things into expressions...